# Setup with two monitors, show overlay on one but not on the other

Tags: video, live, mixing

I am setting up a musical project where our ensemble (5 people) will play live music to a silent movie. We seek the best setup for a live performance where:

- the audience sees just the movie (monitor 1), presumably via a beamer or projector in the theater
- the musicians see the movie plus an overlay with time stamp, cues, countdowns etc. (monitor 2, signal through a splitter distributing the signal to 5 screens).

We would like to be able to

- command everything from one laptop (with two hdmi ports, one connected to the beamer, the other to the splitter, if that’s a good idea?)
- have the movie and the overlay in separate files, and mix the two together in real time for the musicians, in order to be able to edit them easily during the rehearsal process
- control the settings (resolution, warmth, saturation etc.) of both monitors separately (the beamer will be different for every performance, but the ensemble will use the same screens every time)

I’d think this should be a fairly standard application, but am unable to find the right software to do so.

I hope I explained clearly what we are looking for. All hints that can point me in the right direction are much appreciated. Also tips for user friendly software to create and tweak the overlay (timing is crucial since in some scenes we are really playing in sync with the situations as they happen in the movie – sound effects etc.) are welcome.